# Access multiple where clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not usually working with MS Access, but there is some database that needs to be a bit updated and unfortunately that responsibility lays on me atm.

I'm having hard time building a query that will return something for me.
Its about selecting these things from db where *isValid* equals *FALSE* and *UID* (it's a string) starts with FF letters, so following my logic I just made FF* to select every string what starts with FF letters.
Issue is, it returns null, nothing is populated by that query, its empty. I'm out of ideas..

```
    SELECT Lista.[Nr Maszyny], Lista.[Nazwa], Lista.[UAP], Lista.[Linia], Lista.[GAP], Lista.[Status], Lista.[UID]
FROM Lista
WHERE ((Lista.[isValid])=NO) AND ((Lista.[UID])=FF*);
```

Comment: See [LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Like` pattern match for *UID*.  If you're running the query from the Access query designer or elsewhere with DAO, what you already had is close to what you need:

```sql
WHERE Lista.[isValid]=False AND Lista.[UID] Like 'FF*';
```

If you will be running the query from ADO/OleDb, you need a different wild card character:

```sql
WHERE Lista.[isValid]=False AND Lista.[UID] Like 'FF%';
```

Comment: Well, that was relatively easy, thank You!
Somehow MS Access is quite hard to understand for me, I'm usually working with RODOTEC programs and other stuff for corp, usually in C++ and this one became somehow, umm, hard ;)

Comment: See whether you find the Access query designer generally helpful.  You can switch between Design View and SQL View to see how the same query is presented in both views.  And that can help you understand Access' SQL syntax ... and its peculiarities.